# Localizing datetimes in Rails I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

In my locale rails console, I can see that I have the following locales available via the I18n gem

```
> I18n.available_locales
=> [:en, :de, :es, :ja, :"pt-BR", :"zh-CN", :"zh-HK", :"zh-TW"]
```

I try using `localize` with a specific date format in English -

```
> I18n.with_locale("en") { I18n.l(Time.zone.now, format: "%B, %Y") }
=> "April, 2016"
```

Which works great. Then I try the same thing with Spanish and Japanese -

```
> I18n.with_locale("es") { I18n.l(Time.zone.now, format: "%B, %Y") }
=> "s, 2016"
> I18n.with_locale("ja") { I18n.l(Time.zone.now, format: "%B, %Y") }
=> "s, 2016"
```

It looks like the month name is being translated as `"s"`.

The rails I18n gem [definitely defines month names](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/es.yml#L19..L32) for the above locales. Does the `#localize` method even make use of those, or is it trying to pull from elsewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: `I18n.with_locale("es") { I18n.l(Time.zone.now, format: "%B, %Y") }` works for me, but `I18n.with_locale("ja") { I18n.l(Time.zone.now, format: "%B, %Y") }` doesn't. What version of rails are you using?

Comment: have your rails/gem project defines additional translations? seems that something that was broken there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I received the same set of outputs as [you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2490003/user2490003) have mentioned.The following are the steps I followed to debug the behaviour.

1. Checked if [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) is part of my rails application by checking the Gemfile.lock (**Actually, it is not**). The I18n gem that is part of my Gemfile.lock is a dependency from [activesupport gem](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support.rb#L99)
2. Checked I18n load path for any translations file for "es" locale `I18n.load_path`. There were none.
3. Went through the I18n.translate method for how it handles date and time formats. The format directives [%a, %A, %b, %B, %p, %P] in the format string are only used for localization (day, month, meridian (AM/PM) indicator - both shorter and longer formats) since only those contain language texts.

> I18n.with_locale(:en) { I18n.localize(Time.zone.now, format: "%B, %Y") }

internally calls

> I18n.translate(:"date.month_names", :locale => :en)[Time.zone.now.mon]

that returns `"April"`

Similarly,

> I18n.with_locale(:es) { I18n.localize(Time.zone.now, format: "%B, %Y") }

internally calls

> I18n.translate(:"date.month_names", :locale => :es)[Time.zone.now.mon]

But there are no translations available,

> I18n.translate(:"date.month_names", :locale => :es)
>
> => "translation missing: es.date.month_names"

`Time.zone.now.mon = 4`.So, it returns `"translation missing: es.date.month_names"[4]` which is `"s"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis, that makes perfect sense now (was wondering in particular how `"s"` kept being returned :) ). I think my fundamental mistake was assuming `rails-i18n` is included by default, and it is not. I'm guessing if I add that gem in it will have translation files from spanish, japanese, etc.... Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue, i used `I18n` for localizing my rails application for `spanish`. while doing time translation it was working fine for english as follows:

```
   I18n.l(raw_date.to_time, format: :long) = "Tuesday, July 11, 2017"
```

For Spanish i was getting

```
  I18n.l(raw_date.to_time, format: :long) = "a, t 11, 2017"
```

I updated my `es.yml` document with `date`, `day_name`, `month_name`, `abbr_day_names`, `abbr_month_names` as follows:

```
es:
 date:
   day_names:
    - domingo
    - lunes
    - martes
    - miércoles
    - jueves
    - viernes
    - sábado
   month_names:
   -
   - enero
   - febrero
   - marzo
   - abril
   - mayo
   - junio
   - julio
   - agosto
   - septiembre
   - octubre
   - noviembre
   - diciembre
 time:
  formats:
   long: '%A, %B %d, %Y'
   short: '%b %d, %Y'
```

After that for `spanish` i got the desired result.

```
I18n.l(raw_date.to_time, format: :long) = "viernes, julio 21, 2017"
```

on going through documents i found out that by default `I18n` will include 
 `date`, `day_name`, `month_name`, `abbr_day_names`, `abbr_month_names` for english, where as for spanish and other languages of interest we need to add these fields in the respective `yaml` documents that we are maintaining. [This](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale) is the link to get these fields for respective languages.